# Service without Activity. how?

Tags: android, service

I am new to android.. just started writing service using activity..
i want to know if there are any other ways to trigger a service without the use of activity? like when a new message arrives, the service need to start running..

if so, how?

Thank you..

Comment: Please consider adding more to your question. What specific trigger are you expecting to start your service, for example?

Comment: that's what the question for! 
are there any others ways to trigger a service..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the abstract, what you want is a [manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that then starts the service.

That being said, there is no support in the Android SDK for events fitting the description of "when a new message arrives".